# How do I write instructions to compare fields like `Date` and `Time` in SQL with `Date` and `Time` as parameters?

Tags: mysql

I have the following Java code to access DB2 to find if a record exists:

```
public static boolean isMailStored(Connection connection, Date giornogiorno,Time oraora) {  
    try {
        System.out.println("oraora: "+oraora);
        String CHECK_MAIL = "select count(*) from x.MAILDAIMAP where MNROMAIL = ";
        CHECK_MAIL = CHECK_MAIL + oraora;           
        System.out.println("Statement: "+CHECK_MAIL);
        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(CHECK_MAIL);
```

The `System.out.println` displays:

```
oraora: 10:27:20
Statement: select count(*) from x.MAILDAIMAP where MORAMAIL = 10:27:20
COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.DB2Exception: [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/NT] SQL0104N  an unespected token ":27" was detected after "where MORAMAIL = 10".  The tokens provided may include: "CONCAT".  SQLSTATE=42601

at COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.SQLExceptionGenerator.throw_SQLException(Unknown Source)
at COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.SQLExceptionGenerator.throw_SQLException(Unknown Source)
at COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.SQLExceptionGenerator.check_return_code(Unknown Source)Error...

at COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Statement.execute2(Unknown Source)
at COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Statement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
at parthoOriginale.Email.isMailStored(Unknown Source)
at parthoOriginale.ReadMail.processMessages(Unknown Source)
at parthoOriginale.ReadMail.main(Unknown Source)
```

`MORAMAIL` is defined as Time in DB2. Why does this error occur? How do I write instructions to compare fields like `Date` and `Time` in SQL with `Date` and `Time` as parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Think of Date and Time fields as really just being String/Varchar fields with constraints on the format.  When querying against them, treat your comparison values as string, i.e. put them in quotes.

```
CHECK_MAIL = CHECK_MAIL + "\"" + oraora + "\"";
```